# Energy flow in an ecosystem

Tags: homework, ecology

What are the mistakes in here?

The image below shows a part of the energy flow diagram in an ecosystem.

[image]

**1. Part P of the biomass of the primary producers does not get consumed. Give a concrete example of how this energy can get to the decomposers.**

I think this energy can get to the decomposers, because the biomass simply dies. E.g. dead animals, dead trees, etc.

**2. The amount of energy that is represented by R may end up with the decomposers in different ways. Name three ways.**

I can come up with natural cell dead (dissimilation after assimilation).

**3. The energy that is released through dissimilation, is not only released in the form of heat. What can this energy 'Q' be used for by the organism?**

I think this energy (e.g. dissimilation of glucose) could be used for movements by the organism.

Comment: The energy released as Q will be used by the organism to do any task not just movement. Energy R can also be consumed by other organism which may later die and then be consumed decoposer

Comment: What makes you think there are mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

1. You are right but a small correction: **P** represents primary producers. So the answer is just dead plants or tissues such as broken branches.
2. Death, excretion because of turnover (which includes urine or other metabolites), tissue turnover (shedding of dead cells, molting etc)
3. Maintenance, locomotion, repair, immunity